# JNI - Can I use RegisterNatives without calling System.loadLibrary for native plugins?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have a C++ application that uses plugins (it dynamically loads certain shared lib files). I'm having some trouble understanding what I need to do to call into dynamically loaded native code from Java.

Do I *have* to use System.loadLibrary/System.load to 'preload' native shared objects ("plugins") to be able to call into that native code? Or would I be okay only calling RegisterNatives from within the plugin after loading it in my native code? I've already called System.loadLibrary for my main native application lib -- its the subsequent plugins the native lib loads that this question is for.

And if I can get away with only calling RegisterNatives what would happen if I suddenly decide to unload a plugin and the JVM tries calling a native method that was inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least Android VM requires that all native methods must be "registered" when the class is instantiated. That's why `System.load()` is usually called in static constructor, and not later.

The two ways to resolve native methods are through `RegisterNatives()` in `JNI_OnLoad()` or though name matching (C exported functions names as reported by `javah`).

You can look for function pointers for `RegisterNatives()` in all loaded modules, or load more modules and get pointers from them. `RegisterNatives()` may be called at any time, and if you really want to unload some plugins you can make use of `UnregisterNatives()`.

The latter was introduced to support the following flow (pseudo-code follows):

```
SwitchPlugin() {
    UnregisterNatives();
    unloadPlugin(oldHandle);
    newHandle = loadPlugin(newPluginName);
    RegisterNatives();
}
```

Your app will probably crash miserably if it tries to *use* a native method that is implemented in an unloaded plugin or after it is unregistered with `UnregisterNatives()`.

Comment: I don't believe the initial sentence is true, as if it were, declaring a native method and loading the implementation later (but before usage) would not work.  In fact it does, and if the loading is skipped, the runtime exception only occurs when at attempt to utilize the missing method is made, **not** when a class of which it is a member is instantiated.

Comment: @chris-stratton: are you speaking about Android implementation?

Comment: as long as I loaded all of my class ids beforehand, calling RegisterNatives after loading the native plugin seems to work fine